# Adding contextual data to a shared object

Tags: c#

I'm trying to come up with a generic model for associating some contextual data with an object in C#. I have built a caching system that can be described as follows...

Background Story -> The cache is a singleton implementation that provides "readonly" access to frequently requested information that is part of a custom CMS implementation that I use for various asp.net applications. I update the data via a desktop application I have written and the next time the web server loads the cache my changes are reflected to visitors.
My cache adheres to the following...

1. Every object has a unique id
2. Any object can be associated with any other object by an id mapping defined in an association table
3. No matter how many associations to a particular object exist, only one instance of that object is loaded into the cache.

For example...Object A might associate to a collection of Object C's. Similarly Object B might also associate to a collection of Object C's. If one were to request an Object C with id 23 from an instance of Object A and then request an Object C with id 23 from Object B, they would get a handle to the same instance of Object C.

I now have some data to add into the picture but the data does not belong to Object A by itself and it does not belong to Object C by itself. The data is information specific to the association of Object A with Object C.

1. My First Idea: Keep the additional data separate from Object C since it doesn't actually belong to Object C by itself. Maintain this information within Object A and allow it to be looked up in a Dictionary. I don't like the way the data has to be accessed in this approach. I would rather have direct access to the additional data via Object C or a derived class for binding purposes and ease of use.
2. My Second Idea: Create a derived class from Object C (call it Object D) that includes the additional contextual data and provides properties for easy access. This addresses the binding and gives me the ease of use that I was looking for. My problem with this approach is that now my Object A is referring to a collection of Object D's and I am required to break my above model by duplicating the entirety of Object A's data just so that I can append some extra association information.

What I would really like is to continue having only one instance of Object C for a given id and append some contextual data and properties that can be easily accessed in the appropriate context. Can this be done? I'm also open for any other suggestions here! I want my solution to be generic and sound so I can forget about it and not have that constant itch to go back and find a better solution.

Comment: How do you think `only one instance of that object`? For example, five list all added the same object, and there're five references of it, but actually `only one instance`. Do we think the same?

Comment: @KenKin Yes. If the cache were loading and there were five lists that each request to add the same object... the first time the object is encountered it would be loaded from the database. For the four following lists, the request would not hit the database and instead would add a reference to our already existing instance.

Comment: Okay. But seems you just want to create a local cache for database?

Comment: @KenKin The caching aspect works fine. I'm trying to find the best way to add some internal data and properties to my object based on the context. So in your example, the 5 lists would need to reference the same object but in one or more of the lists, I want my cache loading algorithm to append some context specific data and accessor properties. The referenced object is still the same in all 5 lists, the additional data is specific to the object's relationship with it's parent object. I would like the data to be accessible through properties for binding and ease of use.

Comment: How do you identify the properties? As the question says, each of them has an identical `Id`, but do you access them all by `Id`?

Comment: What went wrong with your own solution #1 besides 'you did not like it'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with my second idea. Object D became a special type of object that has it's own properties/members/methods but also has a property that returns an Object C. Object D must implement a specific interface to be identified by my caching algorithm. I updated my caching system to ensure that if the Object C returned by the property has already been loaded, that one is returned instead of loading up an additional copy from the db.

Answer (score 0):

The Objec C instances should hold there own data. Of course you can store the "path" in it via what the object was retrieved from the cache (via Object A or Object B), but storing this kind of information in the object, modifies the object, so if it were to be retrieve via another "path", the information will be overrwritten.

A solution could be to clone object C every time it is retrieved from the cache and store your "path" in it, or store your extra data if it came via Object A?

This way, all objects inside your cache are shared as requested, but stand alone once outside the cache.